# socket.io how to send multiple messages sequentially?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io like this

**Client:**

```
socket.on('response', function(i){
    console.log(i);
});
socket.emit('request', whateverdata);
```

**Server:**

```
socket.on('request', function(whateverdata){
    for (i=0; i<10000; i++){
         console.log(i);
         socket.emit('response', i);
    }
    console.log("done!");
});
```

I need output like this when putting the two terminals side by side:

```
Server    Client
0         0
1         1
. (etc)   .
.         .
9998      9998
9999      9999
done!
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
Server    Client
0         
1         
. (etc)         
.         
9998         
9999         
done!
          0
          1
          .
          . (etc)
          9998
          9999
```

Why?

Shouldn't Socket.IO / Node emit the message immediately, not wait for the loop to complete before emitting any of them?

Notes:

1. The for loop is very long and computationally slow.
2. This question is referring to the `socket.io` library, not websockets in general.
3. Due to latency, waiting for confirmation from the client before sending each response is not possible
4. The order that the messages are received is not important, only that they are received as quickly as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server emits them all in a loop and it takes a small bit of time for them to get to the client and get processed by the client in another process.  This should not be surprising.

It is also possible that the single-threaded nature of Javascript in node.js prevents the emits from actually getting sent until your Javascript loop finishes. That would take detailed examination of socket.io code to know for sure if that is an issue. As I said before if you want to 1,1 then 2,2 then 3,3 instead of 1,2,3  sent, then 1,2,3 received you have to write code to force that.

If you want the client to receive the first before the server sends the 2nd, then you have to make the client send a response to the first and have the server not send the 2nd until it receives the response from the first.  This is all async networking.  You don't control the order of events in different processes unless you write specific code to force a particular sequence.

Also, how do you have client and server in the same console anyway?  Unless you are writing out precise timestamps, you wouldn't be able to tell exactly what event came before the other in two separate processes.

---

One thing you could try is to send 10, then do a `setTimeout(fn, 1)` to send the next 10 and so on.   That would give JS a chance to breathe and perhaps process some other events that are waiting for you to finish to allow the packets to get sent.

---

There's another networking issue too.  By default TCP tries to batch up your sends (at the lowest TCP level).  Each time you send, it sets a short timer and doesn't actually send until that timer fires.  If more data arrives before the timer fires, it just adds that data to the "pending" packet and sets the timer again.  This is referred to as the [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).  You can disable this "feature" on a per-socket basis with [`socket.setNoDelay()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setnodelay_nodelay).  You have to call that on the actual TCP socket.

I am seeing some discussion that Nagle's algorithm may already be turned off for socket.io (by default).  Not sure yet.

---

In stepping through the process of socket.io's `.emit()`, there are some cases where the socket is marked as not yet writable.  In those cases, the packets are added to a buffer and will be processed "later" on some future tick of the event loop.  I cannot see exactly what puts the socket temporarily in this state, but I've definitely seen it happen in the debugger.  When it's that way, a tight loop of `.emit()` will just buffer and won't send until you let other events in the event loop process.  This is why doing `setTimeout(fn, 0)` every so often to keep sending will then let the prior packets process.  There's some other event that needs to get processed before socket.io makes the socket writable again.

The issue occurs in the `flush()` method in engine.io (the transport layer for socket.io).  Here's the [code for `.flush()`](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L416):

```
Socket.prototype.flush = function () {
  if ('closed' !== this.readyState &&
                this.transport.writable &&
                this.writeBuffer.length) {
    debug('flushing buffer to transport');
    this.emit('flush', this.writeBuffer);
    this.server.emit('flush', this, this.writeBuffer);
    var wbuf = this.writeBuffer;
    this.writeBuffer = [];
    if (!this.transport.supportsFraming) {
      this.sentCallbackFn.push(this.packetsFn);
    } else {
      this.sentCallbackFn.push.apply(this.sentCallbackFn, this.packetsFn);
    }
    this.packetsFn = [];
    this.transport.send(wbuf);
    this.emit('drain');
    this.server.emit('drain', this);
  }
};
```

What happens sometimes is that `this.transport.writable` is false.  And, when that happens, it does not send the data yet.  It will be sent on some future tick of the event loop.

From what I can tell, it looks like the issue may be here in the [WebSocket code](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/01c6a12de51aa0252a6d624a7a968eb144655c3f/lib/transports/websocket.js#L89):

```
WebSocket.prototype.send = function (packets) {
  var self = this;

  for (var i = 0; i < packets.length; i++) {
    var packet = packets[i];
    parser.encodePacket(packet, self.supportsBinary, send);
  }

  function send (data) {
    debug('writing "%s"', data);

    // always creates a new object since ws modifies it
    var opts = {};
    if (packet.options) {
      opts.compress = packet.options.compress;
    }

    if (self.perMessageDeflate) {
      var len = 'string' === typeof data ? Buffer.byteLength(data) : data.length;
      if (len < self.perMessageDeflate.threshold) {
        opts.compress = false;
      }
    }

    self.writable = false;
    self.socket.send(data, opts, onEnd);
  }

  function onEnd (err) {
    if (err) return self.onError('write error', err.stack);
    self.writable = true;
    self.emit('drain');
  }
};
```

Where you can see that the `.writable` property is set to `false` when some data is sent until it gets confirmation that the data has been written.  So, when rapidly sending data in a loop, it may not be letting the event come through that signals that the data has been successfully sent.  When you do a `setTimeout()` to let some things in the event loop get processed that confirmation event comes through and the `.writable` property gets set to `true` again so data can again be sent immediately.

To be honest, socket.io is built of so many abstract layers across dozens of modules that it's very difficult code to debug or analyze on GitHub so it's hard to be sure of the exact explanation.  I did definitely see the `.writable` flag as `false` in the debugger which did cause a delay so this seems like a plausible explanation to me.  I hope this helps.

Comment: See my note #1. The for loop is actually enormous, so I am sure it not simply a matter of the server running faster than the time it takes for the message to be delivered

Comment: They are in separate consoles

Comment: @JeremiahRose - The point is that you don't control the order unless you write code to control the order.  The coordinate between sending N and receiving some other response is NOT in your direct control unless you write code that forces a particular order.  Also, how are you putting both responses in the same console anyway?  They are different processes client and server.  Without precise timestamps, there's no specific ordering in two separate consoles.

Comment: @JeremiahRose - It is possible that the single-threaded nature of Javascript in node.js prevents the emits from actually getting sent until your Javascript loop finishes.  That would take detailed examination of socket.io code to know for sure if that is an issue.  As I said before if you want to 1,1, then 2,2, you have to write code to force that.

Comment: Yeah I suspect it may be a feature of the event loop but it would be good to get confirmation of this and a solution.

Comment: @JeremiahRose - See the `setTimeout()` idea I added to my answer.  That would tell you whether it's an event loop issue or not.  For testing, you could set the setTimeout time to 50ms or something guaranteed to be long enough to let other waiting messages get run and if that does "fix" things, then you can experiment with how low you can make the timer.  This is an experiment to attempt to prove if its an event loop issue.  I'm not sure this is the best solution to the issue yet, but we're trying to prove whether it is or isn't an event loop issue.

Comment: @JeremiahRose - Another possible issue is Nagle's algorithm at the TCP level (see what I added to the end of my answer).

Comment: Using 'setTimeout(sendNextMessage(), 0)' recursively solved the problem, though I am not sure why. If you're able to provide an answer for that then I'll mark that as accepted. Thanks heaps!

Comment: @JeremiahRose - OK, I did some debugging of socket.io and came up with a plausible explanation for what you observe.  See what I added to the end of my answer.